# Onclick in <a> cause reloading of the page insted of executing JS code

Tags: javascript, html

My URL: http://www.example.com/?product=3&url=XYZ

My code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo();return false;">link</a>
```

After click, page is reloading, instead of executing foo() function.

JS is enabled. Body of foo():

```
function foo() { alert("sss"); }
```

Probably, this problem is caused by URL of my site. XYZ parameter is a url of a website but with something like "%C5%82%C3%B3" instead of special characters (something like after using htmlspecialchars()).

What is interesting, after click the page is reloaded with the "normal" URL, something like: http://www.example.com/?product=3&url=http://www.example.com (WITH special characters like " / ").

What can I do to resolve this problem?

**EDIT**
Above code works fine. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Post your real code please and we'll help you find where you have it wrong.

Comment: I change my real code to that simple piece I posted and it is still working incorrectly

Comment: Check if you have any javascript errors on the page.

Comment: The given part works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/AfBzB/

Comment: Most probably you have a js error on your page and javascript is not executing at all. Install Firebug, open it, refresh the page and look for errors. The code looks right.

Comment: @Jack That code works just fine, so the problem is elsewhere. http://jsfiddle.net/Hn6XQ/10/

Comment: Could you post a link to the page or the HTML content? I don't think there's any circumstance under which your tag should reload the page ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/brymck/xwhPe/)). Can you verify that your script is loading and that you haven't set the `target` of the `<a>` tag to something (other than `_self`)?

Comment: I haven't set the target and my script is loading. I agree that code looks fine, I think that the URL is a problem. I'm installing Firebug, will answer in a minute.

Comment: No JS errors in console. Firebug shows that foo() wasn;t executing.. What is even more interesting, the reloaded page is blank..

Comment: OK guys, I figured it out - the problem was the name of the function, it was reserved. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, there's definitely something else going on here. Here's a minimal example that works just fine:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="foo();return false">link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo() { alert("hi"); }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Assigning onclick inline is not a good practice, and you should be doing something like

```
<a id="someId" /* ... */ >
// ...
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo() { alert("hi"); return false; }
document.getElementById("someId").onclick = foo;
</script>
```

but in any case, the most likely culprit is that your script has a syntax error somewhere and is not loading at all. You can verify this by setting `onclick="return false"`. If *that* doesn't work, it's likely you have some other event handler that's being triggered. But because the above -- all we know of your code -- works, it's unlikely anyone here can diagnose what the problem is without more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Nevermind this, I fully assumed your code wasn't working and the below did. But I guess the code you posted was already correct.

---

On a seperate note, you should avoid using attributes like `onClick`, create event handlers instead (I suggest looking at jQuery).

Comment: That won't work. you need to `return foo();` or just use `onclick="foo"`.

Comment: The `return false;` works just fine there. What's the problem with using inline `onclick`?

Comment: My bad, I did some bad testing. The reason inline `onClick` is bad practice is because you are combining javascript and html when they could be seperate. In simple cases this poses no problem, however when your systems become more complicated and you need to change something, you would have to change onClick everywhere instead of changing one event handler.

Comment: The issue here is that with inline `onclick` it's not using a return value from `foo`. If you use something like `document.getElementById("someID").onclick = foo` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

i tried the same code in my systm.the code is workin and the alert box is visible.

My code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo();return false;">link/a>
```

and javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function foo()
    {
    alert("sss"); 
 }

</script>
```

i am using vs2008